# Moving windows setting messed up

Tags: windows

I've done something wrong here :P

This happens when I move a window:

[image: Picture]

I've messed with some settings a while ago, a YouTube tutorial said this would make my PC faster, but it is simply just too annoying. I can't seem to find the setting anymore, as I upgraded to Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot your machine?  How about you tell us what settings you have been changing, might give us an idea, what setting you might have messed up.

Comment: @Ramhound Edited.

Comment: @iversen I can't understand what that screenshot is showing + your question is really missing the problem description. **I did something and my computer is messed up now** is verrryyyyy big question

Comment: So you changed something, how tell us, what that something is.  This avoidance isn't appreciated

Comment: I remember this tip from 1996 :) Even then it didn’t have much of an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've uncheched the **Show window contents while dragging** checkbox under Performance Options. Do the following:

1. Click Start, type **This PC**
2. Right-click **This PC** and click **Properties**
3. Click **Advanced system settings**
4. Click the **Settings** button under **Performance**
5. See if the mentioned checkbox is checked, if not, check it.